# Running javafx application thread more than once

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I am working on an java application where I'm using java swing forms and javafx FXML stage.I am new to javafx.Now in my app I'm calling javafx fxml stage having controller,from a swing form.I'm calling the fxml stage from the swing form on clicking a button like this----
                     **Application.launch(MyFxml.class);**

This works fine.But when I go back again from the fxml stage to the swing form by clicking a button in the following way and try to access the javafx fxml stage I'm getting exceptions.
                             **new MySwingform().setVisible(true);**

The following code snippet is used to call up the swing form---

```
    public void goBack(ActionEvent ev){

    Platform.exit();

    new MySwingform().setVisible(true);
}
```

The exception I'm getting is "Application launch must not be called more than once".So,how to get rid of this so that we can run the javafx application thread over and over again without any error?Thanks in advance for your useful suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

To show JavaFX components within a swing application, [you should place them on JFxPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm) instead of launching a new fx application.

To do the opposite (embed swing components within a Java FX application), you need [Java FX 8's SwingNode](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html).

Comment: Thanks @assylias,but still I want to implement that way.On searching over the internet I got to know about Service and Task to get concurrency.But I am having difficulty implementing that into my program.

Comment: @HimanshuGogoi Calling `Application.launch` starts the FX Thread - and you can't start more than one FX Thread. So you have to adapt to the way the API is designed I'm afraid.